# Inserting Korean characters via JDBC through MYSQL stored procedure giving error

Tags: java, mysql, unicode, jdbc, utf-8

I believe I am using the correct queryString params for jdbc connection

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databasename?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&noAccessToProcedureBodies=true
```

My database is [correctly set-up](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/faqs-cjk.html#qandaitem-B-11-1-2) to support utf-8 (default character variables).

```
character_set_client utf8
character_set_connection utf8
character_set_database latin1
character_set_filesystem binary
character_set_results utf8
character_set_server latin1
character_set_system utf8
```

My sproc defines each parameter as utf8 where necessary

```
IN _shortDesc MEDIUMTEXT character set utf8,
```

CALLing the sproc through MySQLWorkbench works as expected. 
However, calling it from Java results in an exception

```
java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xAC\xED\x00\x05t\x00...' for column '_shortDesc'
```

Interestingly, changing sproc definition for relevant fields to `utf16` or `ucs2` results in no exception but incorrect Korean characters in the table.

I have also tried using a byte array when building the sql parameters in Java

```
getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))
```

But the exception is still thrown.

What is the correct way to set this up to correctly pass CJK characters through Java to MySQL via a stored procedure?

***EDIT***
I am using SimpleJdbcCall from the spring framework

```
DriverManagerDataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
ds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://server/test?characterEncoding=utf8");
ds.setUsername("user");  
ds.setPassword("pass");

// must explicitly declare params
SimpleJdbcCall jdbc = new SimpleJdbcCall(ds)
    .withProcedureName("sp_gms_addGameTranslationsTest");

SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource()
    .addValue("_test", "그러나 사디라");

jdbc.execute(in);
```

Comment: Could you paste the string (or the offending part of it) that you are trying to insert? needless to say, \xAC\xED is not valid UTF-8, and those zero bytes look strange, too.

Comment: Any Korean or Chinese or Japanese text will fail - here's a snippet that works fine when calling the sproc directly (so its not the text that is wrong - it must be jdbc driver). 겠겠지만

Comment: Unable to reproduce the problem with MySQL 5.5 and Connector/J 5.1.20: this works as expected https://gist.github.com/2918685

Comment: Might just be a version of driver issue. I'm using springs jdbc package. I tried your code using 5.1.20 and worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root problem was I am using springframework `SimpleJdbcCall` to execute the stored procedure. That simplifies configuration by using databases metadata to figure things out for you. By explicitly declaring my input parameters when using that object, the call works fine.

e.g.

```
DriverManagerDataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
ds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://server/test?characterEncoding=utf8");
ds.setUsername("user");  
ds.setPassword("pass");

// must explicitly declare params
SimpleJdbcCall jdbc = new SimpleJdbcCall(ds)
    .withProcedureName("sp_gms_addGameTranslationsTest")
    .declareParameters(
        new SqlParameter("_test", Types.VARCHAR)
);

SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource()
    .addValue("_test", "그러나 사디라");

jdbc.execute(in);
```

I realise this answer was impossible to arrive at from my original question, so I have added an edit.